# the number of rows in the data does not match the number of tips in the tree in phyloglm

Tags: r, regression, phylogeny

I do not seem to able to see where I am getting things wrong. I am using the package phylolm to do some regressions with phylogenetic data

my model is not running and returns the error : Error in `phyloglm(testVar ~ ...the number of rows in the data does not match the number of tips in the tree.`

I have done everything to check but the species in my tree and those in my data are matching.
my code is

```
diet<-read.csv("dat.csv",h=T,dec = ".")
phy=read.nexus("ConsTree.tre")# the phylogenetic data
keep.spp<-levels(diet$ScientificName)
phylo<-drop.tip(phy,phy$tip.label[-match(keep.spp, phy$tip.label)])

setdiff(phylo$tip.label,diet$ScientificName)# this confirms that all is OK
t1<-phyloglm(testVar~Var1+Var2+Var3, diet, phylo)

t1<-phyloglm(testVar~Var1+Var2+Var3, diet, phylo, 
             method = c("logistic_MPLE","logistic_IG10","poisson_GEE"), 
             btol = 10, log.alpha.bound = 4,
             start.beta=NULL, start.alpha=NULL,
             boot = 0, full.matrix = TRUE)

   #
    Error in phyloglm(testVar~Var1+Var2+Var3,..the number of rows in the data does not match the number of tips in the tree.
```

Can anyone point where I am getting things wrong?

Comment: If you are still around could you publish your ConsTree.tre and the header to dat.csv? I'd like to know the data set you are working with.

Answer (score 2):

aplogies for being blind to this small thing...
I was supposed to rename my row.names in my data

```
row.names(diet)<-diet$ScientificName
```